# C++ Hello world keeps giving me errors in Visual Studio 2019

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-studio-2019

I'm just trying to print hello world using C++ but all I get is build errors. The error list shows 412 errors and they're mostly "Cannot open source file" followed by a file name that I haven't heard of.

It also says the WindowsSDKDir property is not defined and the solution I found was to repair visual studio when I looked up this problem. I completed repairing visual studio and I have the C++ selected in the workloads.

Even when I select "Console App" during initial set up it'll end up giving me the same errors even though that is supposed to set up a basic environment for Hello World.

My code is simply just to print out hello world.

```
#include <iostream>

void output();

int main()
{
    output();
}

void output()
{
    std::cout << "Hello World!" << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: I am not certain what you did, but I bet that you did not install C++ environments in the installer.

Comment: Right click on the project in "Solution Explorer" click General and look at the "Windows SDK Setting" There should be more than 1 choice in the combo box. Try a different one.

Comment: `The error list shows 412 errors` [Edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/65947516/edit) the question and copy/paste the first dozen or so of those errors from the Output window (not the Error List window),

Comment: I suggest that you could reset your setting in `Tools->Import and Export Settings Wizards->Reset all settings`. If it doesn't work, maybe you need to reinstall Windows SDK or Visual Studio.

Answer (score 0):

So I just uninstalled Visual Studio completely and then reinstalled it. I realized I could have just modified it using the installer, but basically after selecting the C++ workload I made sure every box was selected on the right hand side. I don't know if I needed it all but I just installed everything to be sure and it finally worked.